# Custom plugins vs query tags: advantages and implementation

Tags: add-on-development, query

An answer to [another question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/133/filtering-member-list-from-multiple-member-groups/140#140) touched on the use of writing custom plugins as a more robust alternative to writing a SQL query in a template via the `{exp:query}` tag.

- What are the advantages/pitfalls of using a custom plugin over the `{exp:query}` tag?
- What patterns should be used to maximise reusability (eg multiple plugins vs single plugin with multiple methods etc)
- How best should custom plugins of this sort be documented before handing off an EE install?

Extra credit for code examples!

Comment: I think the answer (and comments on the answer) you are referencing may be [this one](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/140/22).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The advantage of using a custom plugin (per-project usually) is that you will invariably come up with several small utility tasks to perform during the course of development (not just query-related). It's far cleaner to house these functions under one roof, in one file, rather than sprinkle your templates with custom queries, PHP blocks, and your **/third_party** folder with a half dozen simple plugins that do one tiny thing.

I would argue strongly in favour of keeping all custom functionality for a site within one package (if not one plugin ... sometimes you'll need an extension as well, and in more complex cases a module). So much less clutter, plus you can use class variables for commonly-used data throughout all of your custom functions (say, an API key if you're making custom API calls, etc).

As for documentation - using the plugin `usage()` function is the way to go for plugins - you can document everything and have it visible right from the Plugins screen in EE. For your extensions and modules, you can use [PHPDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc) with each function, or just add paragraph-style comments with each function to explain what your code does, and then optionally add [EE comments](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/comments.html) in your templates wherever you call your custom functions so that folks know that it's a) custom, and b) what it does.

The disadvantage of going the custom add-on route would be if you, say, only have a couple of custom queries across your site, and no need for custom helper functions - in which case sticking with the Query module omits any overhead from loading another class (i.e., your custom plugin) needlessly. Plus - no need to write a custom plugin!

Comment: Very much +1 on keeping your custom stuff to within one package. I have a Github repo set up (a clone of an old repo by Mark Huot) that builds you basic package scaffolding, complete with Phing buildscript so you can just tell it the package name and have it clone that to all the right places. Repo is here: https://github.com/adrienne/base.ee_addon

Answer (score 13):

It is also important to note that the Query Module *is not safe* if you are allowing any user-entered data. The *only* thing the Query Module does, besides adjusting for pagination if present, is passes the string through to the CI db class (in EE 2.5.3 this is line 181 of `/system/expressionengine/modules/query/mod.query.php` )

`$query = $this->EE->db->query($sql);`

The CodeIgniter documentation specifically states that you should escape your queries using one of the escape functions (see this page: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html); however, there is NO escaping being done in the EE core code.

The way around this is to use a custom addon, and ensure that you escape your queries (or use CI's Active Record, which does automatic escaping) within your addon methods.