# How/where do I place commonly used functions across multiple plugins?

Tags: add-on-development, plugin

I have 2 or 3 custom plugins that I'm using on a project. In each file I have a number of 'helper' functions (is this the correct terminology?) that perform a task that might be required in a few of the functions within each plugin.

At the moment I have a copy of each helper function in each of the plugins. The code is the same and I realise this isn't the right way to go. My question is, where to put them and how to reference them from within each of these custom plugins?

Thanks in advance!

Jim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest bundling all of your custom functionality for the project into one add-on ([more on this thinking](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/192/custom-plugins-vs-query-tags-advantages-and-implementation/196#196)) - then you can use EE's helper implementation for this. (Have a look at the [recommended add-on directory structure](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/packages.html).)

In your add-on package, add a **helpers** directory, and in it place one or more PHP files which contain your function(s). Be sure that they are all named with a **_helper.php** suffix.

```
my_addon
    helpers
        my_functions_helper.php
    mod.my_addon.php
    pi.my_addon.php
    (etc)
```

Then in your plugin or module:

```
$this->EE->load->helper('my_functions');
// you can now use all of the functions contained in my_functions_helper.php
```

But, if you want to stick with multiple add-ons, you can certainly include any shared file that lives inside your **third_party** directory:

```
include(PATH_THIRD.'/my_addon/libraries/my_library.php');
```

(The location and file naming after `PATH_THIRD` is up to you.)

Comment: Loving that answer Derek. So if I understand you correctly, $this->EE->load->helper('my_functions'); will only find my_functions_helper.php if it is part of the same addon? As I have 4 or 5 plugins, I may be better off going the 'include' method.

Comment: Correct - only if it's part of the same add-on (or if the helper is located in the system-wide **helpers** directory - but it's not advisable to add to that).

Comment: I would not include library, but actually load it using code like this:   

    `$this->EE->load->add_package_path(PATH_THIRD.'my_addon/');  

    $this->EE->load->library('my_library');  

    $result = $this->EE->my_library->some_function();  

    $this->EE->load->remove_package_path(PATH_THIRD.'my_addon/');`

Comment: Yuri - I like that, but I also don't ... it's messier, and it needs to happen every time you want to call one of the shared functions. What's the advantage in this case over the `include()`?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you'll want to use a separate directory in the `system/expressionengine/third_party/` hierarchy just for your library.

So if your plugins are plug1 and plug2, they'll normally live in `system/expressionengine/third_part/plug1/pi.plug1.php` and `system/expressionengine/third_party/plug2/pi.plug2.php`.  For a common library referenced in both plugins, just put it somewhere like `system/expressionengine/third_party/plugs/pluglib.php`.

Comment: Thanks Scott! That's just what I was after. One more question if I may: how do I include the pluglib.php file in plug1 and plug2?

Comment: You'll likely want the `PATH_THIRD` constant: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/constants.html

Comment: Hey, I actually like Derek's suggestion better than mine, BTW.